# SQL select issues after join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have some issues when I want to select some rows after joining two tables.

I have 3 tables, Library can contains multiple books,
Books belong to one or more Library and have a BookTypeId for each language the book is available.

```
Library
Id|Name

Books
Id|IsAvailable|LibraryId|BookTypeId

BookType
Id|DisplayName|Language
```

After the join it's create this table

```
Id|Name    |IsAvailable|Language

0 |library1|          0|Book1_EN
0 |library1|          1|Book1_FR 
0 |library1|          0|Book1_ES
1 |library2|          1|Book1_EN
1 |library2|          1|Book1_FR
1 |library2|          1|Book1_ES
1 |library2|          1|Book2_EN
```

Library can contains multiple books,
Books belong to one or more Library and have a BookTypeId for each language the book is available.

```
SELECT l.Id, l.Name, BookType.TypeName, Books.IsAvailable
FROM [Library] l
RIGHT JOIN Books ON l.Id = Books.LibraryId             
LEFT JOIN BookType ON Books.BookTypeId = BookType.Id     
WHERE (BookType.Language='Bookname1_FR' AND Books.IsAvailable='1') AND (BookType.Language='Bookname2_EN' AND Books.IsAvailable='1') 
ORDER BY l.Id ASC
```

But my request return null, I think it's because of my join which duplicates some raws of Library table in my joining table.

Do you know how I have to modify my WHERE clause to get librairies which sell those 2 books at the same time ? Maybe by using 2 SELECT and INTERSECT the results ?

Comment: Why RIGHT JOIN? Humans usually find it very hard to understand those... Most people prefer LEFT JOIN if an outer join has to be made!

Comment: @jarlh I would guess it's designer generated? It usually is when I see a combination of left and right joins in the same query

Comment: @TomV, probably, no humans involved...

Comment: `which sell those 2 books`, which books? in where you are filtering by book language not the book itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHERE condition cannot be satisfied. Modify that. Maybe you mean OR?

```
WHERE (BookType.Language='Bookname1_FR' AND Books.IsAvailable='1') OR (BookType.Language='Bookname2_EN' AND Books.IsAvailable='1')
```

UPDATED: you should use GROUP BY for your requirement

```
SELECT l.Id, l.Name, BookType.Language
FROM [Library] l
RIGHT JOIN Books ON l.Id = Books.LibraryId             
LEFT JOIN BookType ON Books.BookTypeId = BookType.Id         
WHERE Books.IsAvailable='1'
GROUP BY l.Name, BookType.Language
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
ORDER BY l.Id ASC
```

Comment: No, I mean AND do you know how I can satisfy the WHERE condition ? Doing two SELECT requests and INTERSECT the results ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l.Id, l.Name, BookType.TypeName, Books.IsAvailable
FROM [Library] l
RIGHT JOIN Books ON l.Id = Books.LibraryId             
LEFT JOIN BookType ON Books.BookTypeId = BookType.Id     
WHERE (BookType.Language='Bookname1_FR' AND Books.IsAvailable='1') AND (BookType.Language='Bookname2_EN' AND Books.IsAvailable='1') 
ORDER BY l.Id ASC
```

BookType.Language can not be 'Bookname1_FR' and 'Bookname2_EN' at the same time. May be you mean this:

```
SELECT l.Id, l.Name, BookType.TypeName, Books.IsAvailable
FROM [Library] l
RIGHT JOIN Books ON l.Id = Books.LibraryId             
LEFT JOIN BookType ON Books.BookTypeId = BookType.Id     
WHERE BookType.Language IN('Bookname1_FR', 'Bookname2_EN') AND Books.IsAvailable='1'
ORDER BY l.Id ASC
```

Comment: No sorry, it's like WHERE clause with OR, thanks for the response

Comment: @RomainXam, You have no OR in your statement... You should use IN or OR

Comment: But I want librairies which sells those 2 books at the same time

Comment: @RomainXam, this changes your question don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

First you have bad where clause. You change the left join into an inner join when you put a where condition (other than ID is null) on the table on the right side of the join. When you need to do this, you should put it in the ON condition. Read:
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN

Now, your WHERE conditions (Which should be in the ON clause per the previous paragraph) are impossible to meet, Let me explain why.

(BookType.Language='Bookname1_FR' AND Books.IsAvailable='1') AND (BookType.Language='Bookname2_EN' AND Books.IsAvailable='1')

In any one record, the field BookType.Language will only have one value. You are asking it to simulatnaeously be 'Bookname1_FR'  and 'Bookname2_EN'. If you want all the records that have either of those two values what you need is an OR condition.

If you need the data to contain book records that always have child records for both the 'Bookname1_FR'  and 'Bookname2_EN', then you need to join to the the Book type table twice once for each condition. In this case, I am not sure you want a LEFT join to begin with. If both records must exist, it is likely you wanted inner joins. As a guess, this might be more what you are looking for if you want teh book to have records for both languages:

```
SELECT L.Id, L.Name,  B.IsAvailable, BT1.TypeName,   BT2.TypeName
FROM [Library] L
JOIN[Books] B
  ON Ll.Id = B.LibraryId             
JOIN BookType BT1 
    ON BT1.BookTypeId = BookType.Id     
JOIN BookType BT1 
    ON BT2.BookTypeId = BookType.Id  
WHERE (BT1.Language='Bookname1_FR'  
AND BT2.Language='Bookname2_EN' 
AND B.IsAvailable='1' 
ORDER BY L.Id ASC
```

I also changed teh right join to an inner join absed onteh fact that you were looking for data field form teh Libraby table that appeared to be necessary to the query. Since it was on the wrong side of the outer join (it is rare to want to order by a field that might contain lots of nulls), I suspect you really want an INNER join.

You never want to mix a left join and right join in the same query as it is confusing to figure out what the data intersections should be when you try to change the query two years from now.  Another thing I notice is that you only aliased one table. It is better to alias all tables if you are aliasing (and I do think aliasing makes it easier to read).You need to think about making this code more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

This returns two rows, one for each of the languages. I guess that's what you want since TypeName is in the results. That's not a column I see in your table schemas though.

It doesn't appear that the outer joins are really necessary so I've switched them to inner joins.

```
SELECT l.Id, l.Name, bt.TypeName, b.IsAvailable
FROM
    Library as L inner join Books as b on b.LibraryId = l.Id
WHERE b.IsAvailable = '1' and (
    SELECT count(distinct bt.Language) /* distinct may not be strictly necessary */
    FROM Books as b2 inner join BookType as bt on bt.Id = b2.BookTypeId
    WHERE b2.Id = b.Id and bt.Language in ('Bookname1_FR', 'Bookname2_EN')
) = 2
```